# How to calculate cumulative sum for sequential dates with breaks in SQL?

Tags: mysql, date

I have a data set as below:

```
Sr. No. ID  Date    Value
1   123456  4/27/2017   90.75
2   123456  4/28/2017   90.75
3   123456  4/29/2017   90.75
4   123456  4/30/2017   90.75
5   123456  5/1/2017    90.75
6   123456  5/2/2017    90.75
7   123456  5/3/2017    90.75
8   123456  5/4/2017    90.75
9   123456  5/5/2017    90.75
10  123456  5/6/2017    30.75
11  123456  5/7/2017    30.75
12  123456  5/8/2017    30.75
13  123456  5/17/2017   35.70
14  123456  5/18/2017   35.70
15  123456  5/19/2017   35.70
16  123456  5/20/2017   35.70
```

I want to calculate cumulative sum as divided by a sequence of dates, so that every break in a date sequence, the cumulative sum starts again. My data should look like below:

```
Sr. No. ID  Date    Value   Cumulative Sum
1   123456  4/27/2017   90.75   90.75
2   123456  4/28/2017   90.75   181.5
3   123456  4/29/2017   90.75   272.25
4   123456  4/30/2017   90.75   363
5   123456  5/1/2017    90.75   453.75
6   123456  5/2/2017    90.75   544.5
7   123456  5/3/2017    90.75   635.25
8   123456  5/4/2017    90.75   726
9   123456  5/5/2017    90.75   816.75
10  123456  5/6/2017    30.75   847.5
11  123456  5/7/2017    30.75   878.25
12  123456  5/8/2017    30.75   909.00
13  123456  5/17/2017   35.70   35.70
14  123456  5/18/2017   35.70   71.40
15  123456  5/19/2017   35.70   107.10
16  123456  5/20/2017   35.70   142.80
```

However, I am currently using lag functionality in SQL as per below code:

```
select distinct 
           b.ID, 
           b.DATE, 
           VAL, 
           (case when DATE_SUB(b.DATE,1)=lag(b.DATE,1,0) 
                    over(order by b.ID,b.DATE asc) 
                      then sum(VAL) 
                     over (partition by b.ID order by b.DATE asc) 
                      else VAL end) as cummulative_sum from b
```

It gives me the output :

```
Sr. No. ID  Date    Value   Cumulative Sum
1   123456  4/27/2017   90.75   90.75
2   123456  4/28/2017   90.75   181.5
3   123456  4/29/2017   90.75   272.25
4   123456  4/30/2017   90.75   363
5   123456  5/1/2017    90.75   453.75
6   123456  5/2/2017    90.75   544.5
7   123456  5/3/2017    90.75   635.25
8   123456  5/4/2017    90.75   726
9   123456  5/5/2017    90.75   816.75
10  123456  5/6/2017    30.75   847.5
11  123456  5/7/2017    30.75   878.25
12  123456  5/8/2017    30.75   909
13  123456  5/17/2017   35.70   35.7
14  123456  5/18/2017   35.70   980.4
15  123456  5/19/2017   35.70   1016.1
16  123456  5/20/2017   35.70   1051.8
```

The cumulative sum starts again after the new date - see record 13-16 in expected and actual result.

Comment: Are you using Mysql or Sql-server ? conflicting RDBMS are tagged. Please clarify!

Comment: Mysql. I am actually working with dataframe objects through spark - using in the form of Sql tables.